# Switching Between Cameras, Crash on Nexus S

Tags: android, android-camera

When switching between the rear-facing and front-facing camera, I am running into the following error on a Nexus S (Android 4.1.2):

```
E/CameraHardwareSec(90): ERR(virtual android::status_t android::CameraHardwareSec::setParameters(const android::CameraParameters&)): preview is running, cannot change size and format!
```

This is immediately followed by:

```
06-30 16:43:38.961: E/AndroidRuntime(10946): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
06-30 16:43:38.961: E/AndroidRuntime(10946):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
06-30 16:43:38.961: E/AndroidRuntime(10946):    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1410)
06-30 16:43:38.961: E/AndroidRuntime(10946):    at com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView.initPreview(CameraView.java:279)
06-30 16:43:38.961: E/AndroidRuntime(10946):    at com.commonsware.cwac.camera.TexturePreviewStrategy.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(TexturePreviewStrategy.java:45)
06-30 16:43:38.961: E/AndroidRuntime(10946):    at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:368)
...
```

This is despite the fact that I call `stopPreview()` on my rear-facing camera preview before calling `setParameters()` with a new preview size (suitable for the FFC). The same code works on other devices (e.g., Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4).

Does anyone have an idea of how to work around this problem, besides choosing a preview size available to both cameras? That solution could work, but I have no way of ensuring that there *is* a common preview size between the two cameras, plus it artificially limits the preview size.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is a longer dump from LogCat, showing my stopping of the preview, then starting it later and crashing. This one shows an artificial one-second delay added in via `postDelayed()`; that did not clear up the problem:

```
06-30 17:20:14.375: D/CameraView(12663): stopping preview
06-30 17:20:14.414: I/CameraHardwareSec(90): int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThreadWrapper(): calling mSecCamera->stopPreview() and waiting
06-30 17:20:14.492: I/CameraHardwareSec(90): void android::CameraHardwareSec::stopPreviewInternal() : preview not running, doing nothing
06-30 17:20:14.492: I/CameraHardwareSec(90): int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThreadWrapper(): return from wait
06-30 17:20:14.492: I/CameraHardwareSec(90): int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThreadWrapper(): exiting
06-30 17:20:14.500: W/SecCamera(90): int android::SecCamera::stopPreview(): doing nothing because m_flag_camera_start is zero
06-30 17:20:14.507: W/SecCamera(90): int android::SecCamera::stopRecord(): doing nothing because m_flag_record_start is zero
06-30 17:20:14.507: I/SecCamera(90): DeinitCamera: m_cam_fd(39)
06-30 17:20:14.523: I/SecCamera(90): DeinitCamera: m_cam_fd2(40)
06-30 17:20:14.550: E/CameraHardwareSec(90): preview window is NULL!
06-30 17:20:14.550: I/CameraService(90): Destroying camera 0
06-30 17:20:14.550: I/CameraHardwareSec(90): int android::HAL_camera_device_close(hw_device_t*)
06-30 17:20:14.550: I/SecCamera(90): DeinitCamera : already deinitialized
06-30 17:20:14.554: W/AudioFlinger(90): session id 206 not found for pid 90
06-30 17:20:14.558: W/AudioFlinger(90): session id 207 not found for pid 90
06-30 17:20:15.480: E/DemoCameraHost(12663): facing: 0, useFFC: true
06-30 17:20:15.480: E/DemoCameraHost(12663): facing: 1, useFFC: true
06-30 17:20:15.480: I/CameraService(90): Opening camera 1
06-30 17:20:15.480: I/CameraHardwareSec(90): int android::HAL_camera_device_open(const hw_module_t*, char const*, hw_device_t**): open camera 1
06-30 17:20:15.484: E/SecCamera(90): initCamera: m_cam_fd(39), m_jpeg_fd(0)
06-30 17:20:15.484: I/SecCamera(90): Name of input channel[1] is S5KA3DFX
06-30 17:20:15.496: E/SecCamera(90): initCamera: m_cam_fd2(40)
06-30 17:20:15.496: I/SecCamera(90): Name of input channel[1] is S5KA3DFX
06-30 17:20:15.496: I/SecCamera(90): initCamera : initialized
06-30 17:20:15.496: I/SecCamera(90): Name of input channel[1] is S5KA3DFX
06-30 17:20:15.496: I/CameraHardwareSec(90): int android::HAL_camera_device_open(const hw_module_t*, char const*, hw_device_t**): opened camera 1 (0x412688a8)
06-30 17:20:15.496: I/AwesomePlayer(90): setDataSource_l('/system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg')
06-30 17:20:15.504: I/CameraHardwareSec(90): int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThreadWrapper(): starting
06-30 17:20:15.504: I/CameraHardwareSec(90): int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThreadWrapper(): calling mSecCamera->stopPreview() and waiting
06-30 17:20:15.507: W/SecCamera(90): int android::SecCamera::stopPreview(): doing nothing because m_flag_camera_start is zero
06-30 17:20:15.515: D/dalvikvm(12663): GC_CONCURRENT freed 159K, 4% free 8249K/8519K, paused 53ms+7ms, total 98ms
06-30 17:20:15.519: I/AwesomePlayer(90): setDataSource_l('/system/media/audio/ui/VideoRecord.ogg')
06-30 17:20:15.535: I/CameraHardwareSec(90): void android::CameraHardwareSec::stopPreviewInternal() : preview not running, doing nothing
06-30 17:20:15.535: E/CameraHardwareSec(90): preview window is NULL!
06-30 17:20:15.539: I/CameraHardwareSec(90): virtual android::status_t android::CameraHardwareSec::startPreview() : deferring
06-30 17:20:15.640: D/CameraHardwareSec(90): mPreviewHeap(fd(39), size(460800), width(640), height(480))
06-30 17:20:15.640: I/CameraHardwareSec(90): int android::CameraHardwareSec::previewThreadWrapper(): return from wait
06-30 17:20:15.640: D/CameraView(12663): initPreview() called, setting up 320 x 240
06-30 17:20:15.644: E/CameraHardwareSec(90): ERR(virtual android::status_t android::CameraHardwareSec::setParameters(const android::CameraParameters&)): preview is running, cannot change size and format!
06-30 17:20:15.648: D/AndroidRuntime(12663): Shutting down VM
06-30 17:20:15.648: W/dalvikvm(12663): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c33300)
06-30 17:20:15.679: E/AndroidRuntime(12663): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 17:20:15.679: E/AndroidRuntime(12663): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
06-30 17:20:15.679: E/AndroidRuntime(12663):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
06-30 17:20:15.679: E/AndroidRuntime(12663):    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1410)
06-30 17:20:15.679: E/AndroidRuntime(12663):    at com.commonsware.cwac.camera.CameraView.initPreview(CameraView.java:280)
06-30 17:20:15.679: E/AndroidRuntime(12663):    at com.commonsware.cwac.camera.TexturePreviewStrategy.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(TexturePreviewStrategy.java:45)
06-30 17:20:15.679: E/AndroidRuntime(12663):    at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:368)
...
```

Comment: There is [this](https://android.googlesource.com/device/samsung/crespo/+/7ac60f8c902354ba14013054f92013a9616a3221) commit from Samsung that seems to be fixing a similar crash but it was merged way back in Gingerbread (I assume you're running JB?). Other than that, I've only found line 1598 [here](https://android.googlesource.com/device/samsung/crespo/+/jb-release/libcamera/SecCameraHWInterface.cpp) where the error is actually triggered. The preview is on its own thread, but skimming through the code, the locks seem sane. It could still be a race condition, I would try adding sleep()s.

Comment: @Deylan: "I assume you're running JB?" -- yes, 4.1.2. "I would try adding sleep()s" -- a `postDelayed()` of 1000ms between stopping and starting the preview did not help. I added a longer LogCat block, from just before I call `stopPreview()` through the exception. From the log messages, it's almost as if `stopPreview()` is broken, as the Nexus S seems to think that no preview is running, which I can't explain.

Comment: I suggest one of two things - 1) capturing the logcat from a camera change from the default camera app and comparing the code flow or, even better, 2) consulting the source for the official camera app (namely, `switchCamera()`@2245 [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera/+/android-4.1.2_r2/src/com/android/camera/Camera.java) ). I've not used the camera APIs but looking at the code, they actually stop and release the camera entirely, not just stopping the preview.

Comment: @Delyan: "they actually stop and release the camera entirely, not just stopping the preview" -- yeah, as it turns out, so was I. I just reconfirmed that the old camera will release before the new camera is opened -- no change in behavior. I'll poke through the rest of `switchCamera()` and will see what else they might do that might fix matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I found my problem. I was turning on preview mode before I thought I was, which caused problems when I later set the preview size.

Moral of this story: when in doubt, set breakpoints on every one of your uses of `Camera`, and make sure the order of events is what you think it is.